# Invertible with unimodular diagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Given a real matrix $A$ of size $n \times n$ and a complex diagonal matrix $X$ of the same size with unimodular diagonal elements, i.e., $\lvert X_{ii} \rvert = 1$.

For which $A$ is $X - A$ invertible for any such $X$?

Is it sufficient that $A$ has no unimodular eigenvalue $\lambda_i$, i.e., $\forall i: \lvert \lambda_i \rvert \neq 1 $? - No, as answered in the comments.

Is it sufficient that $A$ is stable, i.e., $\forall i: \lvert \lambda_i \rvert < 1 $?

Comment: No. Try $X=diag(1,-1)$ and $A=\begin{pmatrix}2&3\\1&2\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: @Chrystomath Ok, thanks for the counterexample. I like to suggest another condition on $A$.

Comment: A sufficient condition would be $\|A\|<1$. Since $A$ and $X$ need not commute, the eigenvalues of $A$ by themselves do not give enough information. For example, if $A$ is *diagonalizable* then yes, the last condition is sufficient.

Comment: Are matrices allowed to have complex-number entries?

Comment: @BenGrossmann $A$  is real, but $X$ is complex.

Comment: An equivalent condition is that $XA - I$ is invertible for any such $X$

Comment: @Chrystomath If $A$ is diagonalizable, why is stability enough?

Comment: @BenGrossmann Because then $\|AX^{-1}\|\le\|A\|\|X^{-1}\|=sp.rad.(A)<1$. I meant diagonalizable wrt an orthonormal basis.

Comment: @Chrystomath Ah ok, that's an important distinction. So by "diagonalizable", you effectively mean "normal"

Comment: @BenGrossmann Ok, I assume the diagonally similar is sufficient too, i.e., $\exists 
 \textrm{ diagonal  } Y: \lVert Y A Y^{-1} \rVert < 1$.